# Search with multiple selects that include tags

Tags: search, tags

I need to make custom search for specific house projects in my new wordpress site.

[image]

It needs to have 4 dropdown lists - 1 [number 2] for categories and 3 [numbers 3,4,5] for tags.

Tags need to be defined within the code because from 13 tags on whole site, 4 are for one dropdown, 5 are for second one a 4 are for third.

Is there any option to do this?

I made the dropdown for categories with this tutorial:
http://www.webstutorial.com/wordpress-multiple-category-search/content-management-system-cms/wordpress-cms
and by including only categories that i need to:

```
<div><?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=1&include=4,5,6,7'); ?></div>
```

But WordPress doesn't have function like wp_dropdown_tags to make something like this with tags

On Codex ( www.codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags ) there is something like: function drop_tags()
but this only works within the_loop() and lists all tags.

It needs to list defined tags, and search only by those that were chosen.

Hope you understand what i mean and have any solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define **any** taxonomy in the arguments:

```
wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=post_tag');
```

Comment: This seems to work.
So simple to make and i was searching for hours.
Thank you very much.